# DateTimePicker set Calendar and Time culture

Tags: wpf, calendar, culture, avalondock

Is it possible set specific culture for `DateTimePicker` control? I would like use this specific culture on format name of moths and time format. For Example I create specific culture:

```
CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("sk-Sk");
```

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try adding:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(FrameworkElement),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage("sk-Sk")));
```

or

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(FrameworkElement),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```

to your applications
    StartupEventHandler

```
    public App()
    {

        DispatcherUnhandledException += new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventHandler(App_DispatcherUnhandledException);
        Startup += new StartupEventHandler(App_Startup);
    }


    protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
    {
        FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(
                typeof(FrameworkElement),
                new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                        XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag)));

        base.OnStartup(e);
    }
```

This should set the culture info for all WPF controls (not sure if you really want to just change the culture for the DateTimePicker)

Comment: I use WPF with MVVM design, I don’t that is suitable way.

Comment: This question is rather old, but if you want to use MVVM you could bind the Language attribute of your MainWindow to the connected datacontext.  Then you only have to change the Language property.